# Send email using gmail: The operation has timed out

Tags: asp.net, .net, email, smtp

I´m trying to configure my console application to send an email to the gmail relay server.

the code i´m using is the next :

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            string header;
            string body;
            string emailTo;
            string emailFrom = "anton.selin@inbox.com";

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the header : ");
            header = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the message body : ");
            body = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your email : ");
            emailTo = Console.ReadLine();

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("anton.selin1@gmail.com", "**********");
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom,"anton selin");
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailTo));
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.Subject = header;

            Console.WriteLine("Sending email...");
            smtpClient.Send(mail);

            Console.WriteLine("Email sent...");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

when i run the code it gives me a timeout error :

```
{"The operation has timed out."}
```

how can i configure my application to be able to send email from console app or web app(from localhost)?

Comment: stacktrace would help too see if the connect operation or something else timed out

Comment: Google help page: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for this, I think this is your issue

```
string emailFrom = "anton.selin@inbox.com";
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("anton.selin1@gmail.com", "**********");
mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom,"anton selin");
```

you are using gmail to send your mail whereas you should be using `anton.selin@inbox.com` credentials to send mail and not Gmail's

Try this code to mail :

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress(Username);
mail.To.Add(emailTo);
mail.Subject = Subject;
mail.Body = Body;

SmtpServer.Port = 587; // Also Add the port number to send it, its default for Gmail
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Timeout = 20000; // Add Timeout property
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks it worked well; i think the problem was with this line of code :  smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;